# Problems with changing read more text when using snippet summaries in Blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm trying to change the text of the read more button in Blogger.
I've been searching everywhere in the code for  or  but it doesn't exist.

But here's what I found:

```
    <div class='mobile-index-arrow'>&amp;rsaquo;</div>

    <div class='mobile-index-contents'>
      <b:if cond='data:post.thumbnailUrl'>
        <div class='mobile-index-thumbnail'>
          <div class='Image'>
            <img expr:src='data:post.thumbnailUrl'/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </b:if>

      <div class='post-body'>
        <b:if cond='data:post.snippet'><data:post.snippet/></b:if>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So I guess I have to add something to this "snippet part", but I don't really know what to add...
Please, does anyone know how to change the read more text? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1:**

You can change the text in **read more** button from Blogger Layout.

Go to **Dashboard** > **Layout** > **Main** > **Edit**

[image]

**Method 2:**

Go to **Dashboard** > **Template** > **Edit HTML**

In post section find this code (below post-body part)

```
    <b:if cond='data:post.hasJumpLink'>
       <div class='jump-link'>
         <a expr:href='data:post.url + &quot;#more&quot;' expr:title='data:post.title'><data:post.jumpText/></a>
       </div>
    </b:if>
```

Replace `<data:post.jumpText/>` with whatever text you want to display in place of *Read More*

**eg:**

```
    <b:if cond='data:post.hasJumpLink'>
       <div class='jump-link'>
         <a expr:href='data:post.url + &quot;#more&quot;' expr:title='data:post.title'>View Post</a>
       </div>
    </b:if>
```

**Method 3:**
Add the this script at the end of  `<b:includable id='post' var='post'>` inside `main section`.

```
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType not in {&quot;static_page&quot;,&quot;item&quot;}'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
             $(&quot;#summary<data:post.id/> .post-entry a.more-link&quot;).html(&quot;<data:post.jumpText/> &lt;i class=&#39;fa fa-long-arrow-right&#39;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&quot;);
        </script>
    </b:if>
```

With this you can change **Read More** text from dashboard, as described in *Method 1*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Simr. I've tried that, but the read more text won't change :(

Comment: @Em_ek ,i have updated the answer, added another method to replace _Read More_ text. Try it and post the result.

Comment: Thanks again @simr, but I can*t find that piece of code. I can't find anything related to jump-link, jump-break or more-link. It simply doesn't excist in my code :( The url to my blog is: http://flora-inspiro.blogspot.se/

Comment: Looks like you are using custom theme, no wonder above code wasn't there. And **Read More** text is generated by javascript, and to make it more difficult, javascript code that generates **Read More** text is obfuscated.

Comment: Well that explains a lot... But is it still fixable? I mean is it possible to change the read more text even if the javascript is obfuscated?

Comment: @Em_ek , i have updated the answer once again, add the script from **Method 3** inside `<b:includable id='post' var='post'>` and just before `</b:includable>` .

Comment: Thanks a lot! But unfortunately I can't make it work :( I past it as you said after <b:includable id='post' var='post'>, I also tried to place it in  other places inside main.  <b:includable id='main' var='top'>
   <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>(tried here)
    <b:include data='post' name='post'/> (tried here)
   </b:loop>(tried here)
   <b:include name='nextprev'/>
  (tried here) </b:includable> Am I doing somthing wrong?

Comment: it should work, I can add this code in your blog. ill contact via your blog if its ok with you.

Comment: That would be great! Thakns a lot!

Answer (score 0):

checked Method 1: which is the best solution
Go to Dashboard > Layout > Main > Edit
use Method 3 incase you have edited from HTML