# Change "read more" button text in Blogger Minimum theme

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I have a problem in my blog with "**read more**" text. I would like to change this text to my own language.

I have this blogspot/blogger theme -> http://demo.themexpose.com/?theme=Minimal and I can't change the READ MORE text from anywhere to change it.

I have looked up it into the Layout part and as well as from the Template (Edit HTML) part, but no - nothing.

I have had been searching this "read more" text almost a whole day and I have a hunch, that maybe it could be connected with the code:

```
var _0xeeb6=
```

OR

```
var _0xabfb=
```

inside the HTML.

Can someone help me to figure it out, how to change the READ MORE text?
I would be so happy.

Thank you in advance!

Virginia

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I finally got it myself.

I used these instructions (*the link is below*), **Method 1** and then **Method 3**. I tryed to paste the Method 3 code almost everywhere between these codes and finally the "read more" text changed into my language. Just had to try several times - copied, saved and and refreshed my webblog... then I did it again, deleted the last insert and copied that code into a new location, saved and refresed the blog again and so on... but one moment.. after some coping-excercise it finally changed, so the Method 3 will save the ones who try to change the **"read more"** text. :)

**Check it out:**

> [Problems with changing read more text when using snippet summaries in Blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724188/problems-with-changing-read-more-text-when-using-snippet-summaries-in-blogger/38104893#38104893)